# HDR Beginners Help : Photoshop CS5

Tags: photoshop, hdr, photoshop-cs5

I am just leaning HDR in Photoshop CS5, can anyone recommend some good tutorials?

Answer (score 5):

[This is a tutorial](http://www.graphicmania.net/how-to-create-hdr-photos-in-photoshop-cs5/) is a good start, with explanations of some of the terms. I also think that [basic HDR tutorials](http://www.stuckincustoms.com/hdr-tutorial/) will also be of benefit, given that the concepts are the same between applications. [You can find a myriad of HDR tutorials](http://www.vanilladays.com/hdr-guide/) via web search that should apply to any HDR tool of your choosing.

Answer (score 3):

dpreview has recently posted the first in a series of articles on HDR photography

http://www.dpreview.com/learn/?/Guides/The_art_of_HDR_Photography_part_1_01.htm

This isn't a tutorial as such (specific techniques will be covered in subsequent posts) but it explains in detail the concepts of HDR photography and as such will increase your understanding of *why* you're doing HDR, no simply *how*.

Answer (score 1):

you could also just download the trial version of photomatix which is a popular HDR processor. You can just tell it what files to load and it will make the HDR image from it. then you can use the simple single-click presets to see various mappings to LDR output (i.e. tone-mapping). I found that just using the photomatix wizard prior to really learning the details of HDR was easy.

http://www.hdrsoft.com/download.html#pmp