# How to take HDR photos?

Tags: hdr

I have a [Sony DSC-H10](http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&langId=-1&partNumber=DSCH10#specifications).

I recently learned why good pictures look so good -- their high dynamic range.

Is it possible (and if so, how) for me to take high-dynamic-range photos of scenes, perhaps through some combination of this camera and some software (e.g. Photoshop)?
Or would I necessarily need a better camera in order to do this?

Comment: Have you searched though the other questions with the [tag:hdr] tag?

Comment: @ChrisF: Nope, I hadn't, actually. I'll take a look at them, thanks.

Comment: You can certainly use your camera to take images for HDR.  Please read through the topics on HDR and if you have specific questions, ask away.  Also see this:  http://www.stuckincustoms.com/hdr-tutorial/

Comment: @MikeW: Thanks for the ideas/link! I'll definitely take a look at it. :)

Comment: Take a look at my answer in this question, this should satisfy all your needs. http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/what-is-hdr-photography

Comment: Don't want to start a war here, but pictures almost certainly don't look good just because of their high dynamic range - there's been thousands of historic, amazing pictures with low DR.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*We'll leave your second sentence for another debate :) but I highly recommend you at least get a photography book (or an introductory class) which will teach you what to do to get great photos with almost any camera.*

To get an HDR image:

1. **Set your camera on a tripod.**
2. Use either **Manual (M) or Program (P)** exposure modes.
3. It is highly recommended you enable the **2s self-timer** to avoid shake.
4. Fix the **ISO to a low value**, like 100, to maximize image quality.
5. **Repeatedly take a few shots by varying the exposure** as follows:

   1. For P mode, take 3 shots one with EC at -2, the other at 0 and the last at +2. This will work for scenes which exceed the DR of your camera but a little. **OR**
   2. For M mode, you can capture way more dynamic range using more images. In this case, just keep changing your shutter-speed and take a shot every 3 or 4 stops. For example: 1/2000s, 1/250s, 1/30s, 1/4s, up to the limit of your camera. 
      y or Daylight for example)

If you are shooting a very dark scene or something with deep shadows, you may need to increase the ISO on your last shots.

**EDIT** Missing the final steps:

1. Take the set of images shot and **merge them into an HDR image**. There are a number of software to do this and, including Photoshop, in case you already have it. Otherwise, [just Google for *HDR software*](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=hdr%20software).
2. The final step is to **tone-map the HDR image**. This converts it into a *Low Dynamic-Range* images which can be shown on computer screens and printed.
3. Alternately, **you can perform something similar in one step using [Exposure Fusion](http://www.digital-photography-school.com/exposure-fusion-what-is-it-how-does-it-compare-to-hdr-how-do-i-do-it)**.

**NOTE:** On most cameras you would use A (Aperture-Priority) mode instead of P (Program) mode for automatic exposure. However, considering *your camera does not have a physical* aperture, it makes no difference and is actually the reason why there is no A mode on your camera.

Comment: +1 for the "2s self-timer". Alleviates the need to buy another piece of equipment (remote, cable).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use software to do this.
HDR, simply said, is mixing 3+ photos together, and highlight their goodness together.

First, you have to take a Exposure bracketing group, recently any Single-lens reflex camera can do this. Canon, nikon.

Second, import these images to your HDR software（Lightroom;photoshopCS5;photomatix;HDR Darkroom etc）and let it do tone mapping.
Last you can adjust you HDR photo.

There is a website can do an HDR photo online, and they have already make an example for you, in Fotor-HDR：http://www.fotor.com/features/hdr.html

You can find many great HDR photos in 500px.com， IT'S not only about exaggerated effect, HDR means more, you will know it.