# 3d fantasy almost type of picture, how do they do it?

Tags: color-management, hdr, image-manipulation

Hi I have been seeing these nice house shots where it looks like the picture is in a fantasy type of 3d.  It almost looks 3d modeled as opposed to just being a picture.  Can anyone tell me how it's done? Is it the camera or is the colors in photoshop?

http://screencast.com/t/9LleEH4sK764

Comment: In my opinion that is a 3D model using an oldie rendering system with some photo composition added.

Comment: Are you sure that this picture is a real one? As Rafael pointed out, it seems like a 3D model.

Comment: That is way too much HDR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it is most likely achieved using a technique called HDR photography.

See:

- [What is HDR photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/what-is-hdr-photography)
- [hdr](/questions/tagged/hdr) tag

Comment: Also some serious perspective correction going on!

Comment: Yeah, definitely shot with a wide-angle lens. The shadows also look like they may have been painted out. They were at least lightened, I'd guess.

Comment: The HDR seems to be it.  I had seen some other ones and actually some listed on this link above are some that I saw.  I'm going to look into that and I'll mark this as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Likely is 'tone mapped' as well.